# How to use `ngMessages` form validation in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am new to angularjs and I need help figuring out what am I doing wrong. I am using `ngMessages` for form validation but the form submit is not working.

Here is my code:

```js
angular.module("myapp", ["ngMessages"])
```

```css
p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.2/angular-messages.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <form name="myform" method="post" novalidate>

    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="inputName" ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="12" ng-pattern="/^\w+$/" required>
    <div ng-messages="myform.username.$error">
      <p ng-message="minlength">Username should have at least 6 characters.</p>
      <p ng-message="maxlength">Username should have at most 12 characters.</p>
      <p ng-message="required">Providing a username is mandatory.</p>
      <p ng-message="pattern">Username can only be alphanumeric with an optional underscore.</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Angular doesn't typically post forms directly. The common pattern is to call a method on your controller which then uses `$http.post()` (directly or, more preferably, via a service) to post the data to the server.

Comment: @abu, did my answer worked ? or do you need some more info

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ng-submit` basically,

```
<form name="myform" ng-submit="submit(myform.$valid)" novalidate>
```

and then in your controller, you need define a method `submit`

```
$scope.submit = function(isValid){
    if(isValid){
       $http.post('your_post_url_here',your_form_data).then(function(success){
             // success message
       })
    }
}
```